# FBSDKCore can't find RCTBridgeModule.h

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, react-native, fbsdk

In my project I am having a problem with the `fbsdk`. Upon linking the `fbsdkcore` to my project in xcode using the `rnpm` as shown here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios.html

My build now fails due to my `RCTFBSDKCore` cannot find the `RCTBridgeModule.h`, even though I think I have gone through all the neccessary steps to include this, even in the Header Search in build settings as shown below:

Linking Binary w/ Lib:
[image]

And the Header Search:

[image]

After this I am quite lost. I have also tried to update all of my packages without success. And as one can see in the picture below, I have two `fbsdkcore`, is this one too many, because it is only when I try to build the `RCTFBSDKCore` that it fails, it is successfull in the other case.

[image]

Ok, so to my question. Could it be that the library should not be included like that in the first place? If not, what have I done wrong/missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rnpm` [does not support](https://github.com/rnpm/rnpm/issues/144) linking multiple libraries at the moment. Check [this article](https://medium.com/call-stack/login-users-with-facebook-in-react-native-4b230b847899#.wjqwntezj) for setting up RN & fbsdk.

Comment: Thank you! But now that I have successfully cleaned the app I am at my initial problem. I seemed like my fbsdkcore was not working correctly, and that is why I started to link it. I am trying to call getCurrentAccessToken, but it returns a redscreen stating that undefined is not an object.

Comment: Have you tried exposing this method from native code before using it in Javascript?

Comment: Well, actually, I don't know. I posted this as a question with more details on what I have done here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37029783/issues-with-the-accesstoken-in-the-react-native-fbsdk I you wouldn't mind checking it out :)

Comment: But have you finished the guide that I've linked? Remember to use YourAppName.workspace not the Xcode projekt when using cocoa pods.

Comment: Yes I am using the .xcworkspace file. Could I be missing something in my podfile?