# Issues with the AccessToken in the React Native FBSDK

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook, react-native, fbsdk

I am having trouble with my ability to get the AccessToken in the `fbsdk` in React Native.

I am calling the core as suggested by Facebook:

```
const FBSDKCore = require('react-native-fbsdkcore');
const {
  FBSDKAccessToken,
} = FBSDKCore;
```

And in one scenario I try to write the token in the log as suggested by a similair question stated here on SO.

```
    <View>
        <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', padding: 50, marginTop: 250}}>
        <View> 
          <LoginButton
            publishPermissions={["publish_actions"]}
            onLoginFinished={
              (error, result) => {
                if (error) {
                  alert("login has error: " + result.error);
                } else if (result.isCancelled) {
                  alert("login is cancelled.");
                } else {
                  FBSDKAccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken((token)=> {
                        console.log(token);
                      });                          
                  Actions.Navigator()
                }
              }
            }
            onLogoutFinished={() => {
              alert("logout.")}}/>
        </View>
        </View>
    </View>
```

This gives me the redscreen "undefined is not an object (evaluating the FBSDKAccessTokenInterface.getCurrentAccessToken)

Trying to pull off something similair in other parts of the app, of course defining the const `FBSDKAccessToken` first, then calling the `userID` (which should be a part of the `FBSDKCore`) as:

```
<Text style={{fontSize: 18, color:colors.General.navtext}}>{FBSDKAccessToken.userID}</Text>
```

Yields nothing, where I believed it to return the userID of the logged in user. Also, if I try to write out the accesstoken in that same place as:

```
<Text style={{fontSize: 18, color:colors.General.navtext}}>{FBSDKAccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()}</Text>
```

I get the same red screen as before.

I tried to look in to the linking of libraries, but that even caused further problem.

Hence, from this, I am pretty stranded and I would really appreciate some feedback on what has gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
console.log(token.accessToken.toString());
```